# Antlr3 Searchengine Grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr3

Creating a grammar to parse search engine like grammar with antlr3 is a task I need help with.

The grammer should allow for:

- ommiting AND between terms: Example dog cat = dog AND cat
- AND should have precedence for OR: cat dog or boat = (cat AND dog) or
  boat
- arbitrary encapsulation of terms in parentheses : cat OR( dog and
  (fish cow) OR bird)

To implement all the criteria above is a challenge (for me). Please have a look at my grammar an advice errors and fixes as properly satisfying all criteria was not achievable.

**Grammar**

```
tokens {
FOR;
END;
FIELDSEARCH;
TARGETFIELD;
RELATION;
ANDNODE;
}
startExpression  : orEx;

expressionLevel4    
: LPARENTHESIS! orEx RPARENTHESIS! | atomicExpression;

expressionLevel3    
: (fieldExpression) | expressionLevel4 ;

expressionLevel2    
: (nearExpression) | expressionLevel3 ;

expressionLevel1    
: (countExpression) | expressionLevel2 ;

notEx   : (NOT^)? expressionLevel1;

andEx   : (notEx        -> notEx)
(AND? a=notEx -> ^(ANDNODE $andEx $a))*;

orEx    : andEx (OR^  andEx)*;

countExpression  : COUNT LPARENTHESIS WORD RPARENTHESIS (LESSTHEN|MORETHEN) EQUAL? NUMBERS -> ^(COUNT WORD ^(RELATION LESSTHEN? MORETHEN? EQUAL?) NUMBERS);

nearExpression  : NEAR^ LPARENTHESIS! (WORD|PHRASE) MULTIPLESEPERATOR! (WORD|PHRASE) MULTIPLESEPERATOR! NUMBERS RPARENTHESIS!;

fieldExpression : WORD PROPERTYSEPERATOR WORD -> ^(FIELDSEARCH ^(TARGETFIELD WORD));

atomicExpression 
: WORD
| PHRASE ;


LPARENTHESIS : '(';
RPARENTHESIS : ')';

LESSTHEN : '<';
MORETHEN : '>';
EQUAL : '=';

AND    : ('A'|'a')('N'|'n')('D'|'d');
OR     : ('O'|'o')('R'|'r');
ANDNOT : ('A'|'a')('N'|'n')('D'|'d')('N'|'n')('O'|'o')('T'|'t');
NOT    : ('N'|'n')('O'|'o')('T'|'t');
COUNT:('C'|'c')('O'|'o')('U'|'u')('N'|'n')('T'|'t');
NEAR:('N'|'n')('E'|'e')('A'|'a')('R'|'r');
PROPERTYSEPERATOR : ':';
MULTIPLESEPERATOR : ',';

fragment NUMBER : ('0'..'9');
fragment CHARACTER : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'*'|'?');
fragment QUOTE     : ('"');

fragment SPACE     : ('\u0009'|'\u0020'|'\u000C'|'\u00A0');

//fragment UNICODENOSPACES  :  ('\u0000'..'\u0008'|'\u0010'..'\u0019'|'\u0021'..'\009F'|'\u00A1'..'\009F');
fragment UNICODENOSPACES  :  ('\u0021'..'\u0039'|'\u003B'..'\u007E'|'\u00A1'..'\uFFFF');

WS     : (SPACE) { $channel=HIDDEN; };
NUMBERS : (NUMBER)+;
PHRASE : (QUOTE)(CHARACTER)+((SPACE)+(CHARACTER)+)+(QUOTE);
WORD   : (UNICODENOSPACES)+;
```

---

Given the input:

```
title:cats AND  fish OR Bird AND (bird and dirt) OR (bart or title:bard OR bird AND title:dort)
```

This AST is created, note the ( ) which got captured in a WORD term.
[image]

There might be other errors or goofy implementation details. Its my first shot at using antlr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a first go at ANTLR, you did more than a good job.

The fact there's `'('` and `')'` in your `WORD` tokens is because the range `'\u0021'..'\u0039'` contains parenthesis. ANTLR's lexer matches characters greedy, *and* tries to match as much as possible (!). Because of that last rule (matching as much chars as possible), it will create a single token from input like `"(bird"` (a `WORD` token), and *not* two tokens (a `LPARENTHESIS` and a `WORD`). Just make sure parenthesis are not included in whatever `WORD` needs to match.

If I copy your grammar and change `WORD` into:

```
WORD : CHARACTER+;
```

your input is parsed as this:

[image]

### EDIT

> Is it possible to have parenthesis as a normal part of term? e.g have blabla(bla( a)blabla recognized as 2 WORDS? The parser would have to decide if parenthesis introduce a subterm or are just normal characters forming a WORD.

You *could* do it like this on a *lexer-level*, assuming the parenthesis in `(a...` and `...a)` are part of the expression, not part of  a `WORD`:

```
WORD : UNICODENOSPACES ((UNICODENOSPACES | '(' | ')')* UNICODENOSPACES)?
```

Only parenthesis inside a `WORD` are now permitted. You could go further by allowing a `(` at the end of a `WORD` to be valid too, but I'm not sure if that'd be a good idea.

Comment: That solves one issue. Is it possible to have parenthesis as a normal part of term? e.g have blabla(bla( a)blabla recognized as 2 WORDS? The parser would have to decide if parenthesis introduce a subterm or are just normal characters forming a WORD.

Comment: @ThomAS, you accepted this answer, but I just saw your question in the comment. Do you want me to provide an answer, or did you sort this yourself already?

Comment: I would very much appreciate getting your advice, thanks! Can you suggest a solution which allows parenthesis as part of the term?